# How do I have the index of an item in a python list which exactly matches a given regular expression pattern?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Suppose I have a list of string items like the following:

```
lst = ['apple', 'mango', 'MIME']
p = r"MIME" # regex pattern
```

Now, I want to have the index of the item which exactly matches the pattern `p`. Clearly, the answer is `2`. How do I do it?

Comment: `r"MIME"` is not a regular expression BTW, it's just a string. That string may be used as regular expression when you feed it into `re` somewhere…

Comment: Unless you're adding some actual regular expression syntax, your example will do with simply `lst.index(p)`.

Comment: `r'MIME'` is a raw string, using `lst.index(p)` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you code re module is for regular expressions

```
import re
lst = ['apple', 'mango', 'MIME']
p = r"MIME" # regex pattern
for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    if re.compile(p).match(lst[i]):
         print i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

r = re.compile(p)

try:
    print(next(i for i in range(0, len(lst)) if r.match(lst[i])))
except StopIteration:
    print('Not found')
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term value.
Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what
limitations and assumptions apply.